# Rest vs Soap consuming

Tags: xml, web-services

Can anyone help me understanding difference between consuming rest service is different from consuming soap service code wise ?

I need core difference in consuming them

Answer (score 1):

Consuming Soap means you need to pass to the consuming app the wsdl file that contains the definition of the objects and methods in your web service as a web reference. Each time you update anything object class or method in your web service, you need to update the reference in your consuming app.

In order to consume rest service you just need to know the endpoint, the url that the service resides, and any parameters and headers that the web service requires you to have before returning any data back. Once you know that you can just call a httpclient instance and create a request to get or post to that endpoint.

Comment: Aside of "the endpoint, the url that the service resides" (SOAP needs it too) what is core difference between WSDL and "need to know any parameters and headers that the web service requires" as well as payload format if it is REST-POST/PATCH/UPDATE ?

Comment: The wsdl file is much more comprehensive and contains all the information you would ever need to know about like this sample one from tutorialspoint, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wsdl/wsdl_example.htm When you give the consuming app this file it will use that file to create proxy classes on your app for receiving and reading that data.

Answer (score 0):

To me core difference is:

SOAP resides on payload format level while REST is on communication level. Nothing prevents to send SOAP payload through the REST endpoint.

Because of that:

1. SOAP is XML based payload, strictly following WSDL specification and code must consume it accordingly, while REST defines nothing about payload, just a communication.
2. SOAP does not define any transport layers, while REST is only about communication through HTTP. SOAP can be send through any channels - HTTP, JMS, FTP, physically CD/DVD ... who cares :-)
3. Through HTTP SOAP webservice uses only HTTP POST method, while REST defines different HTTP methods for different operations - GET to retrive data, POST to add data, PATCH/POSt to modify existing data and so on...